# Type of tag input in html5

Tags: html

I wanted to know is there someway to make the tag  look like this:

[image]

html is just like this:

is it possible by only using css, please tell me.

## sorry for my poor English.:)

Comment: Are you in search for the datepicker ? If yes please use `<input type="date" >`

Comment: Yes. But i want to pick up month. And by using <input type="month" >, the default choose is looks like day. I'm wondering if the drop down list of input   can be months

Comment: Ok, There is no direct html element to achieve this. You may need to use some custom filters to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a description on hovering you can use title attribute..

Comment: Can you please share some more details about what you actually want to do ?

Comment: i'am tring to using tag<input type="month"> to chosen date.but the default choose is Day. that img i’ve post is just like a drop down list.click to show this list, and in this list there are twelve months.in this img there is twelve months in chinese.i want to pick up some months.